# display-table.htc not functioning when there's a YouTube video on the page

Tags: html, css

Have a look at the following url in IE7: http://rickkuipers.nl/display-table/index.html

As you can see, the display-table.htc doesn't seem to get loaded at all because of the YouTube video (`<object>` tag).

When you click on the link "Switch to version without `<object>` tag of YouTube" you can see that the exact same page WITHOUT the `<object>` YouTube tag works fine.

I've already contacted the author of display-table.htc but I thought I might as well ask it here.

Does anyone know a workaround for the problem?

Note that only removing `type="application/x-shockwave-flash"` from the `<object>` tag also makes it work again. But then the YT video obviously won't work anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SWFObject to dynamically (and also more correctly) load the YTPlayer worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3&video_id=mUCRZzhbHH0",
                   "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);
</script>
```

This way the .htc behavior will not be broken.

**EDIT**
If the above isn't a valid option for you, you can change this in the display-table.htc

```
<public:attach event="ondocumentready" onevent="_(element)" />
```

To

```
<public:attach event="oncontentready" onevent="_(element)" />
```

**EDIT** I have accepted my own answer but please also do note the comment from the creator below.

Comment: Unfortunately `oncontentready` itself is buggy (as far as I remember, it causes problems when there are _nested_ `display:table` elements). So `ondocumentready` has been used _intentionally_ as a more reliable method.

Comment: @MaratTanalin But in this case ondocumentready seems to be even buggier so I'll ahve to go with oncontentready. I seem to have it all worked out now and tested it in IE7. If you have better ideas then I'd be happy to hear :)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently JS API version of YouTube embedding code somehow blocks htc component from running. Probably it's a bug of the YouTube JS API itself.

The issue is not reproducible when using usual embedding code like this (available via right click on YouTube Flash Player -> Copy HTML code):

```
<object style="height: 390px; width: 640px"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/mUCRZzhbHH0?version=3&feature=player_detailpage"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/mUCRZzhbHH0?version=3&feature=player_detailpage" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360"></object>
```

Comment: I was expecting that answer, I now managed to do it by using SWFObject to embed it. Because your answer made me aware of some things and made me think about what would happen if I'd dynamically load the YTPlayer later on, I will +1 your answer. Problem Solved.